# pandas diff() giving 0 value for first difference, I want the actual value instead

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have df:

```
Hour  Energy Wh  
1        4          
2        6           
3        9
4        15
```

I would like to add a column that shows the per hour difference. I am using this:

```
df['Energy Wh/h'] = df['Energy Wh'].diff().fillna(0)
```

df1:

```
Hour  Energy Wh  Energy Wh/h
1        4          0
2        6          2 
3        9          3
4        15         6
```

However, the Hour 1 value is showing up as 0 in the Energy Wh/h column, whereas I would like it to show up as 4, like below:

```
Hour  Energy Wh  Energy Wh/h
1        4          4
2        6          2 
3        9          3
4        15         6
```

I have tried using np.where:

```
df['Energy Wh/h']  = np.where(df['Hour'] == 1,df['Energy Wh'].diff().fillna(df['Energy Wh']),df['Energy Wh'].diff().fillna(0))
```

but I am still getting  a 0 value in the hour 1 row (df1), with no errors. How do I get the value in 'Energy Wh' for Hour 1 to be filled, instead of 0?

Comment: Try this: `df['Energy Wh'].diff().fillna(df['Energy Wh'].iloc[0])`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can just `fillna()` with the original column, without using `np.where`:

```
>>> df['Energy Wh/h'] = df['Energy Wh'].diff().fillna(df['Energy Wh'])
>>> df
      Energy Wh  Energy Wh/h
Hour
   1          4          4.0
   2          6          2.0
   3          9          3.0
   4         15          6.0
```

Answer (score 7):

The first value returned by [`diff()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) is always `NaN`, so it's faster to replace only this value instead of needing to use `fillna()`, just using [`loc[]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Then convert the `float` dtype (introduced by the NaN) back down to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) (if necessary; i.e. if your series doesn't have any other `NaN`s or `float` values):

```
df['Energy W/h'] = df['Energy Wh'].diff()
df.loc[0, 'Energy W/h'] = df['Energy Wh'].iloc[0]
df['Energy W/h'] = df['Energy W/h'].astype(int)
print (df)
   Hour  Energy Wh  Energy W/h
0     1          4           4
1     2          6           2
2     3          9           3
3     4         15           6
```

More general is to do:

```
df.index = [5,6,7,8]
print (df)
   Hour  Energy Wh
5     1          4
6     2          6
7     3          9
8     4         15

df['Energy W/h'] = df['Energy Wh'].diff()
df.loc[df.index[0], 'Energy W/h'] = df['Energy Wh'].iloc[0]
df['Energy W/h'] = df['Energy W/h'].astype(int)

print (df)
   Hour  Energy Wh  Energy W/h
5     1          4           4
6     2          6           2
7     3          9           3
8     4         15           6
```

Comment: thanks, I will try this now. Can I ask why it is important to convert float values to int?

Comment: No, it is not necessary - it is up to you. But if original values are int, only one `NaN` cast column to float. So if need `int`, cast it back to `int` from `float`.

Comment: It would be a useful enhance or modification for pandas `diff()` to overwrite the NaN diff'd value with the corresponding unmodified value; then coerce back to the original dtype. Here you have the common case [`periods=1`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) so we're dealing with the first value `.iloc[0]`, but it could also be -1 for a lagging(?) diff. Seems many of us need this a lot.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach is to avoid `.diff` and use `.shift` with a fill value and explicitly perform the subtraction:

```
df['Energy Wh/h'] =  df['Energy Wh'] - df['Energy Wh'].shift(1, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: This answer is correct, and has the potential advantage of not not changing the dtype from `int` to `float` when calling `diff()`. Not sure why this answer was downvoted. I guess for the purposes of this question dtype may not have been a concern, but I prefer solutions where dtype changes are explicit.

Comment: Performance is another concern with `.diff`. In my practice I wasn't been able to get a result using `.diff` on a table with 1.5M rows. `.shift` took less then 1 sec.